# Django permissions separate users by country

Tags: django, permissions

I have a question regarding permissions. I would like to separate my Users who are marked as Staff ( and can enter the administration page) through countries. So for example an admin from Netherlands can only see and edit the users from netherlands. What is the best approach to do that?
 Should I make the querys in a way so users can only see users from their own country and than I can customize it with permissions?

my models.py defines a country

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', unique=True)
    country = models.CharField("Country", max_length=150, blank=False)
```

and I thought about something like this in admin.py

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ProfileAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(country=request.user.country)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking in the right direction.  It is the proper way to filter objects visible to admins.

Small corrections: the name of the method is [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) and to access the user's country you should use the `profile` relation:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ProfileAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(country=request.user.profile.country)
```

**UPDATE**: To filter users in the standard `User` admin you have to replace the `UserAdmin` with your own subclass:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyUserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(profile__country=request.user.profile.country)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: I tried your code and ran in some problems, well I have extended the User with a OneToOne relationship with UserProfile and I want to filter precisely on a field that belongs to the UserProfile and not the standard User model and the code doesn't seem to work for me here. Since the User model is extended I can still call the fields like so 'country=request.user.profile.country' well at least I thought so. What can be the problem that my admin still sees all the users in the admintool?

Comment: You will see all `UserProfile`s if you are logged as the superuser.

Comment: Do you want to filter the `UserProfile` admin or standard `User` model admin?

Comment: I would like to filter both actually.